# How can one make disappear autohotkey default icon tray when the script is suspended

Tags: autohotkey

How I can make disappear autohotkey default icon tray when the script is suspended? And to appear it once the script is enabled again. The following make the icon disappear but fails to reappear it.

```
Esc:
Suspend, Toggle
Menu, Tray, NoIcon
return
```

Comment: How are you starting it back up? Because if you are just relaunching it via double clicking the file then the icon re appears on mine.

Comment: @ZackTarr what you say is true. But the answer below solves my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in variable [A_IsSuspended](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm#Remarks)  contains 1 if the script is suspended and 0 otherwise.

```
Esc::
    Suspend, Toggle
    If (A_IsSuspended)
        Menu, Tray, NoIcon
    else
        Menu, Tray, Icon
return
```

Comment: How do you get the `Esc::` command to be called again to untoggle it though? Since the file is suspended it wont find that file.  And restarting the script pulls the icon back up too. Is there a way to start a script back up without the icon in the task bar?

Comment: You can use an INI-file to store the suspend state [OnExit](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnExit.htm) and restore this state after restarting or reloading in the auto-execute section.

Comment: My question? If so yes. I was just curious as to an approach to do it. Im not sure if it works for the OP though.